# How to set background for a Steam profile?

Tags: steam

I noticed some of my friends can change their Steam background profile. I searched in "Edit Profile" tab to edit mine but I don't see how.

**Can someone explain how to do this ?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Profile backgrounds are Steam Inventory items that you can get by creating badges and trading (either with friends or through the Steam Marketplace).

[image: Steam Inventory with backgrounds]

Once you get a background item, you can change your background.

[image: selecting a background to set]

Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: I have quiet a lot of diferent background. I never cared enough about them to look up how to, but the "Select Background..."-button is not available to me when I select one of them in my inventory.

Comment: @Zaibis "Select..." appears in "Edit Profile".

Comment: The problem in my case was the fact I don't own any "background items". I'll try to craft some soon !

Comment: @Galabyca You can also buy them from the market (usually they're pretty cheap... $0.15 or less) or trade for them with other people. **However**, as of March 9, either of these methods have a 15 day hold on sales and trades unless both people have Steam Mobile Authentication set up.